# on share, og:url is showing my server, not the facebook tab URL

Tags: facebook, tabs

I've build a tab for my brand page. Problem is when you click to share, the url that appears under my title is to my own domain where the tab is being hosted. How do I have it either hide this URL (I dont want people coming to my server) or change this to be the facebook brand page tab url?

I've already tried editing my meta og:url to show the facebook tab url instead and tried this within the app settings, both did not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it could help: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

Comment: Thanks, I had already looked at that documentation. Everything is working perfectly, except the URL appearing...

Comment: So you set share_url='' and Facebook haven't used it?

Comment: no, when I do that it ignores my other meta data for the tab completely and pulls the info from that URL. I just want that URL to display, but not pull anything from it.